# Get object associated with selected rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to an array of objects.

```
List<Node> nodes = GetNodeList();

m_grid.DataSource = nodes;
```

I then handle the SelectionChanged event.

In the handler for the SelectionChanged event I want to access the selected objects.

All I seem to be able to do is access the value for each cell in the grid rather than the overall object associated with the row.

```
void OnSelectionChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    foreach ( DataViewGridRow row in m_grid.SelectedRows )
    {
        /* Here I want to be able to access the Node object associated with this row*/
    }
}
```

I'm sure it must be possible but I just can't figure it out. I could get the row index and then look back into the array but that seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = MyDataGridView.SelectedRows;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
   DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
   // Do something with your DataRow
}
```

Comment: Ah OK, sorry I'm binding directly to an array of objects. I'll update the code...!

Comment: Brilliant - that's the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From memory, cell will be  DataGridRowView:

```
var drv = cell as DataGridRowView;
var row = drv.Row as MyDataRowType;
```

Anyway, use the debugger to find the Type of `cell`